# Replace String Containing Quotation Marks in Powershell

Tags: powershell

How do I replace a string with quotation marks, with another string that has quotation marks?

I have tried nearly every method I could find online for syntax but powershell just can't recognize what I am trying to do.

Here is a quick example:

```
-replace '2"','7"'
```

I need powershell to search for the quotation as well as the number, so replace just the number is not good enough.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Set str="1"` and `Set str1=%str:"1"="2"%`

Comment: your demo works for me ... with this input string `'one two "three 3" and some other stuff'`, and this `-replace '3"', '7"'`, i get `one two "three 7" and some other stuff` ... so, what is different in your situation?

Comment: For me, Powershell is not finding the 2" and therefore not replacing it with the 7". I need Powershell to find the number two and double quotation marks that is within a string and replace it with the number seven and double quotation marks.